# Поиск при помощи регулярного выражения bash

Tags: bash

Вопрос такой, каким образом можно выполнить поиск контента в строке при помощи регулярного выражения?
Контент заранее неизвестен.

Пример строки: {DOG-1--cats/04/}
Искомый контент: cats (заранее неизвестен)

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Пересмотрел множество манов, но ничего схожего не нашел.(

Comment: `(?<=--)[^\/]*`

Comment: Пойди туда - не знаю куда, найди то - не знаю что?